# c# WebConfig App settings with hex values

Tags: c#, hex, appsettings

I have the following c# code line:

```
Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
```

What I need is to store in the web.config the list of hex values:

```
<add key="BytesVector" value="0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76" />
```

And then user the value like this:

```
 var vector = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BytesVector"].ToString();

 Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { someParsingHere(vector) });
```

> Any clue?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to split the string by ',' and convert to bytes base 16.

Here's an example:

```
string s = "0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76";
var list = s.Split(',');

byte[] bytes = new byte[list.Length];
for(int i=0; i<list.Count(); i++)
{
    bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(number.Trim(), 16);
}
```

Comment: You can supply the full `0x49` format to Convert.ToByte, no need for doing substring.

Comment: Also `byte[] bytes = s.Split(',').Select(e => Convert.ToByte(e.Trim(), 16)).ToArray();`.

Comment: I removed the substring, it's not needed when it's trimmed. And yes, you can also use the one-liner linq solution :)